# Sorting excel sheet in reverse order on basis of created time / reversing the excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, excel-interop

I'm using  Microsoft interop excel to automate the excel workboook
in which i have many worksheets(say 40) which have been created at in seconds gap or even less
now i have to present the worksheet in reverse order i.e the sheet which was created first should come first while opening(currently it comes last) in short I have to sort the excel sheet in reverse order or by time of creation

any help in this matter

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(Form1.strRecentFilename, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp);
        int count = wb.Worksheets.Count;
        Worksheet ws, lastws;
        lastws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[count];
        MessageBox.Show(lastws.Name);
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            lastws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[count];
            ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[i];
            ws.Move(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, lastws);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, **Excel doesn't store the date and time of creation of each sheet**. Yet, every new sheet is added at the end of every sheets of the workbook.
So, you can reverse the order based on this hypothesis.

Here is a VBA macro to do this, you just have to adapt it to interop or C#:

```
Sub reverseOrder()
Dim i As Integer
For i = Worksheets.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Worksheets(i).Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Next i
End Sub
```

It parses sheets from one sheet before the last one to the first one and **move each sheet to the last position**.

Comment: I wonder if creating the sheets in reverse order might be a good idea? If the first sheet is selected, the default for Sheet.Add is Before.

Comment: @Remou: that's also a great idea. I've understood from the OP's question that he couldn't interfere with the workbook while creating the sheets but only afterwards. Hence my solution.

Comment: @JMax thts true..i want to traverse after all sheets are created..
Let me see if its works.....

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have a Worksheets of Workbook in excel file and you need to sort Worksheets  alphabet:

```
   public void SortWs()
   {
        List<Worksheet> for_sort = new List<Worksheet>();

        foreach (Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            for_sort.Add(ws);
        }

        for_sort.Sort(delegate(Worksheet wst1, Worksheet wst2)
        {
            return wst1.Name.CompareTo(wst2.Name);//sort by worksheet's name
        });

        Worksheet ws1, ws2;

        for (int i = 0; i < for_sort.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= wb.Worksheets.Count; j++)
            {
                ws1 = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[j];
                if (for_sort[i].Name == ws1.Name)
                {
                    ws2 = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[i+1];
                    ws1.Move(ws2, Type.Missing);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```